# Why a Combine publisher can still emit values after it emits completion

Tags: ios, swift, combine

Theoretically, in my opinion, a publisher will **not** emit values once it emits a completion event. It is true when I use publishers such as `PassthroughSubject` .

However, as the sample code below, I use a publisher like `Just` or `[1, 2, 3].publisher` and the first subscriber already receives a *completion*. But the second subscriber can still receive the value emitted and a completion event.

Am I misunderstanding something?

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let publisher = Just(1) // or [1, 2, 3].publisher

publisher.sink {
    print($0)
} receiveValue: {
    print($0)
}
.store(in: &subscriptions)

publisher.sink {
    print($0)
} receiveValue: {
    print($0)
}
.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

The output in the console is:

```
1
finished
1
finished
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing twice and each subscriber is getting the value and a completion.

Comment: But, if I subscribe a `PassthroughSubject ` and the subject sends a completion. Then I subscribe the subject again, I will not receive the value again.

Comment: Different publishers have different behaviors.

Comment: The difference is between so-called "hot" and "cold" signaling. Some publishers are meant to model things happening as they are happening (like notification center). Once it happens, future subscribers don't get it (hot). Some are more like a data-structure (e.g. Just) that sends the value to all new subscribers (or else, it could never really work at all in your example since all subscribers happen after) -- this is cold.